# Parsing JSON from AWS lambda payload

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parsing, aws-lambda

I have created a lambda function, based on the event function is calling different part of code. Lambda may call same lambda with different event data. I want to know in which format I need to pass event and how I need to parse it.

when passing event from AWS console it is working fine
Event {"processf": "parent"}

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

function parentLambda(){
    var paramevent="{'processf':'callChildLambda'}";
     var params = {
        FunctionName: 'arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:function:calllambdafromlambda', //remove hardcode
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        Payload: JSON.stringify(paramevent)
        // Payload: String("{'process':'callLambda'}")
    };
    var lambda = new aws.Lambda({
        region: "ap-southeast-1" 
    });

    lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
        } // an error occurred
        else {   console.log(data);
        }           // successful response
    });

   console.log('I am in Parent Lambda'); 
}

function childLambda(){
    console.log('lambda invoked from same lambda')
}


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(event);
        var d=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event));
        console.log(d.processf);
        console.log('Process--------' + String(event["processf"]));
        if (event["processf"] == "parent")
        {

             parentLambda();
        }
        else if (String(event["processf"]) == "callChildLambda")
        {
            childLambda();

        }
        else{
            console.log('not implemented')
        }

};
```

Need to know in which format I need to pass and how to parse while giving if condition.

Comment: Why would you invoke Lambda A from Lambda A? Why not simply call a function within the same code?

Comment: Lambda has timeout limitation, all process can not completed in singleshot. Other way can be sns and step function(for orchestration) , docker(for timeout limit) but my requirement can be satisfied by lambda so don't want to make it complex.